# How can I change the folder where images are stored, from storage to public?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using Voyager Laravel admin panel but it stores image in the storage folder. how can i change this to public folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to run `php artisan storage:link` which creates a symbolic link to "public/storage".

Comment: Eric is a Laravel Ninja, trust him jajajajaja p.s. I love you Eric <3